# "Car" avec plus d'un cas

Tags: conjonctions, subordonnées, coordination

Quand on dit "parce que" on peut ajouter plus de un cas en disant "que" entre les cas, par exemple:

> Elle a quitté Londres parce qu'elle voulait vivre à la campagne et **qu**'elle voulait payer des loyers moins chers.

Comment puis-je dire la même chose mais en utilisant **car** ?

> Elle a quitté Londres **car** elle voulait vivre à la campagne et **?** elle voulait payer des loyers moins chers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En principe, *que* ne sert qu'à répéter une conjonction de subordination. Ceci s'applique y compris aux quelques conjonctions de subordination qui ne se terminent pas par *que* (« si … et que … »), mais pas aux conjonctions de coordination telles que *car*.

Pour faire la conjonction de deux propositions dont la première est introduite par une conjonction de coordination, on a déjà la conjonction *et*, et cela suffit : on ne rajoute pas d'autre mot.

> Elle a quitté Londres car elle voulait vivre à la campagne et **∅** elle voulait payer des loyers moins chers.

De même que, par exemple,

> Elle a longtemps vécu à Londres, **mais** elle voulait vivre à la campagne et **∅** elle voulait payer des loyers moins chers, **donc** elle est partie et **∅** elle s'est installée à Londres.

On peut toutefois trouver la conjonction *car* répétée avec *que*, probablement à cause de la proximité sémantique de *parce que*. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/car) (§C.2) indique que cette reprise est « jugée incorrecte ».