# « Y compris » : Pourquoi dit-on « y » dans ce cas ?

Tags: pronoms, locutions

J'ai déja vu plusieurs de fois l'expression **y compris** mais je n'arrive pas encore à comprendre la raison pour laquelle on utilise le pronom **y**. Par exemple :

> Elle était présente aux naissances des enfants royaux, **y compris** à celle d'Henri.

ou

> En principe, cela ne sert qu'à répéter une conjonction de subordination. Ceci s'applique **y compris** aux quelques conjonctions de subordination qui ne se terminent pas par *que* (« si … et que … »), mais pas aux conjonctions de coordination telles que *car*. ([Source](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11174/358))

Pourquoi on dit **y compris** et pas seulement **compris** ?

Answer (score 5):

« Compris » signifie ici qu'un élément ou un sous-ensemble fait partie d’un ensemble plus grand. Le pronom *y* renvoie à l'ensemble. Dans l'exemple que tu cites, l'antécédent de *y* est « [les] naissances des enfants royaux ».

Le pronom *y* traduit l'omission d'un complément indirect ou circonstanciel (voir le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y) *y*² II.A ; la locution figée est mentionnée en II.A.2.b mais l'usage est très proche de II.A.1 ainsi que de I.A.2). Si l'on séparait les deux propositions, on pourrait écrire

> Elle était présente aux naissances des enfants royaux. La naissance d'Henri est comprise dans les naissances des enfants royaux en question.

Le complément du verbe *compris* est introduit par *dans* ; c'est un complément de lieu, même s'il est métaphorique. Le pronom *y* abrège donc « dans les naissances … ».

On pourrait choisir d'abréger plus ou moins : le pronom n'a pas de véritable valeur sémantique, puisqu'il ne sert qu'à signaler l'omission d'un complément (le lieu dans lequel l'objet est compris) et que ce complément est facultatif. D'ailleurs il existe une construction qui l'omet :

> Elle était présente aux naissances des enfants royaux, celle d'Henri comprise.

Cette formule abrège « …, [la naissance] d'Henri *étant* comprise *dans les naissances des enfants royaux* ». La construction utilisant le pronom *y* a l'avantage d'imposer le sens du mot *compris* signifiant *inclus*, et non celui lié à l'entendement.

On pourrait logiquement dire « …, compris celle d'Henri » (la reprise de *à* est facultative avec la locution figée *y compris*, mais impossible si on veut en faire une proposition à part entière) ou « …, celle d'Henri y comprise ». Je pense que la préférence (qui n'est pas absolue) pour *y compris* antéposé et *compris* seul postposé est à mettre sur le compte des hasards de l'évolution de la langue.